# AHK Send Key Help v1.1-> v2

Tags: autohotkey

On runnign the below script
Followed[SENDKEY_v2](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/howto/SendKeys.htm) syntax in the below code  and ran it in AHK_v2 , but AHK prompts to download AHK_v1.1.

Even tried using parenthesis['Send("{Key}")'] but didn't work.

What's missing?

```
    Left::
  Send"!{Tab}"
  Sleep100
  Send"{Left}"
  return

Right::
  Send"!{Tab}"
  Sleep100
  Send"{Right}"
  return

Down::
  Send"^{Esc}"
  return

Up::
  ExitApp
```

Comment: Try removing the quotes?  E.g., 
```
        Send {Esc}

 Send {Right}

 Send ^c

 Send !{Tab}
```

Comment: @Arctiic Didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works here:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#SingleInstance Force

$Left::
{
  Send "!{Tab}"
  Sleep (100)
  Send "{Left}"
}

$Right::
{
  Send "!{Tab}"
  Sleep (100)
  Send "{Right}"
}

$Down::Send "^{Esc}"
 
$Up:: ExitApp
```

The [$ prefix](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) prevents the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm) command from triggering the hotkey itself.